# When to use axis instead of xlim and ylim in matlab?

Tags: matlab, optimization, graphics, plot

What is the difference between setting `xlim` and `ylim` or `axis`?

I expext that `axis` is not a wrapper for xlim and ylim...

Comment: Additionally of what Adriaan answered, with `axis` you can: `axis equal`, `axis square`, `axis tight` `axis image`, `axis xy` ,...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axis.html):

> `axis(limits)` sets the x-axis and y-axis limits for the current axes. Specify limits as a four-element of the form `[xmin xmax ymin ymax]`. To additionally set the z-axis limits, specify a six-element vector. To additionally set the color limits, specify an eight-element vector.

So they perform the exact same thing, only `axis` can contain all three image axes in one command, whilst `xlim`, `ylim` and `zlim` set only the limits for their respective axis.

`axis` obviously has a lot more functionality, but purely for limits there's no real difference with the one-axis versions.